# Encrypted growing sequence

Tags: mathematics, cipher, pattern, number-sequence

## The following sequence has been encrypted:

`1-0`

`3-0`

`6-1`

`126-2`

`373378-2`

`20532303792-2`

`24311068187968-3`

Can you find the pattern and the next 3 elements?

### Hint a - 2nd April 2020

I'm here giving you the next 2 elements. The pattern and the third element remain for your :)

> `7356612131551389558912-4`
>
>  `651915846947455861534362510912-5`

### Hint b - 10th April 2020

> Factorials are exceedingly used

### Hint c - 15th April 2020

I really thought this puzzle will be solved quickly and without hints ^^, it's among the easiest I posted here!
Alright, giving you another hint, but it is becoming like... so easy!

> At step $n$, there are $n+1$ factorials used!

### Hind d - 3rd May 2020

I'm removing the encrypted part of this puzzle with this hint!

> The sequence's numbers are:
>  `1`
>  `3`
>  `60`
>  `12600`
>  `37337800`
>  `2053230379200`
>  `24311068187968000`

And so on :)

## Hint e - 6th May 2020

Giving you an equivalent function ;)

### Defining $H(n)$

> This puzzle is about $n+1$ factorials so I told myself, why not use [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?
>  $$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$
>
>  Suppose that $P(n)$ is the sequence we want to understand. $P$ for Puzzle
>  $P(1) = 1$
>  $P(2) = 3$
>  $P(3) = 60$ and so on.
>
>  I'm here going to define $H(n)$, $H$ for Hint, using Stirling's formula and such as $P(n)\sim H(n)$ where the sign $\sim$ means that the two quantities are asymptotic: their ratio tends to 1 as n tends to infinity.
>
>  Let $T_n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}2$ and $\displaystyle K(n) = \prod_{k=1}^{n}k^k$ ($K$ is the [hyperfactorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660659/most-simple-expression-of-prod-k-1nkk)) I computed for you: $$H(n) = \dfrac{\pi^{\frac{1-n}2}\sqrt{(n+1)}T_n^{T_n}}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}K(n)}$$

### Computing $H(n)$

> The following Julia script gave me the first elements of $H(n)$
>
>  `|+--------------------+-------------------------------+`
>  `|   P(n)              | H(n) rounded at one decimal   |`
>  `|+--------------------+-------------------------------+`
>  `| 1                   | 1                             |`
>  `| 3                   | 3.3                           |`
>  `| 60                  | 68.8                          |`
>  `| 12600               | 14823.8                       |`
>  `| 37337800            | 45388978.9                    |`
>  `| 2053230379200       | 2501368479610.3               |`
>  `| 24311068187968000   | 3000139818683595001.3         |`
>  `|+--------------------+-------------------------------+`
>
>   `function T(n)`
>  $~~~~$     `n*(n+1)/2`
>   `end`
>
>   `function K(n)`
>  $~~~~$     `k = 1`
>  $~~~~$     `for i in 1:n`
>  $~~~~~~~~$         `k = k*i^i`
>  $~~~~$     `end`
>  $~~~~$     `k`
>   `end`
>
>   `function Hint(n)`
>  $~~~~$     `pi^((1-n)/2)*sqrt(n+1)*(T(n)^T(n))/(sqrt(factorial(n-1))*K(n)sqrt(2)^n)`
>   `end`

### Plots

And I even made some plots for you :)

> [image]  [image]

### Warning!

> The fact that the definition of $H(n)$ is really (really) complicated doesn't implies $P(n)$ is also complicated! It's even the opposite, $P(n)$ is simple to express. Think of it like the Stirling's formula, $n!$ is really simple to express and $\sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ is a little less simple to write.

## Note

Please note that I've changed the values of my sequence after Hint d to make it even easier :)

Comment: Are you sure that the sequence is *encrypted*? It seems like maybe something involving prime numbers but not cryptography...

Comment: @dan1st, yes, it is. I have encrypted it because, otherwise, it would be too easy finding the pattern :) You made me realize, I forgot the cryptography tag! Many thanks ;)

Comment: Heh, I thought your avatar was a piece of the Mandelbrot set until I clicked through to your profile :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor, haha! You did find one of the reason why I chose it :)

Comment: @Randal'Thor, By the way, I went for yours and the link in your description: http://riddled.azurewebsites.net/ isn't working anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. I don't remember seeing this before. Your numbers are

> ${{1+2+\cdots+n}\choose{1;2;\dots;n}}=\frac{(1+2+\cdots+n)!}{1!\,2!\,\dots\,n!}$

The encryption

> simply splits off any final zeros in the decimal representation and gives their count instead of the digits themselves.